# How do I obtain the distances of each point lying inside or outside buffers from the center of buffers?

Tags: polygon, distance, buffer, geopandas

My aim is to obtain the shortest distance between all the points overlain on a polygon and the center of buffers also overlain on the same polygon.

I have done the following to illustrate this:

```
import pandas as pd
import geopandas
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame(
       {'City': ['Fargo', 'Orange', 'Jersey City'],
        'State': ['Nevada', 'California', 'New Jersey'],
        'Latitude': [46.877186  , 33.787914 , 40.728157 ],
        'Longitude': [-96.789803, -117.853104, -74.077644]})
df['Coordinates']  = list(zip(df.Longitude, df.Latitude))
df['Coordinates'] = df['Coordinates'].apply(Point)
gdf = geopandas.GeoDataFrame(df, geometry='Coordinates')
gdf_points=gdf
print(gdf.head())

world= geopandas.read_file(geopandas.datasets.get_path('naturalearth_lowres'))
#nybb=  geopandas.read_file(geopandas.datasets.get_path('nybb'))

# We restrict to USA.
ax = world[world.name == 'United States'].plot(
    color='white', edgecolor='black',figsize=(20,10))
us_states.plot(ax=ax,figsize=(20,10))


# We can now plot our GeoDataFrame.
gdf.plot(ax=ax, color='red')
ax.set(xlim=(-140,-50),ylim=(0,60))


us_name = world[world.name=='United States']
gdf['Coordinates']=gdf.buffer(3)
#gdf.head(5)
gplot=geopandas.overlay(us_name,gdf,how='identity')
gx=gplot.plot(edgecolor='k', alpha=0.5, cmap='tab10', ax=ax)
gdf.plot(ax=ax)

df1=pd.DataFrame(
      {'Points':['Point1','Point2','Point3','Point4','Point5','Point6'],
         'Latitude':[44.773491,30.287765,41.279906,45.234565,31.23345,38.778987],
         'Longitude':[-94.789323,-114.565309,-72.055234,-93.230988,-112.233456,-72.239989]})
df1['Coordinates']  = list(zip(df1.Longitude, df1.Latitude))
df1['Coordinates'] = df1['Coordinates'].apply(Point)
gdf1 = geopandas.GeoDataFrame(df1, geometry='Coordinates')
print(gdf1.head()) 

gdf1.plot(ax=gx,color='red')
gx.set(xlim=(-140,-50),ylim=(0,60))
centroid_of_buffers=gdf['Coordinates'].centroid
min_dist=centroid_of_buffers.distance(gdf1[gdf1.Coordinates=="POINT (-93.230988 45.234565)"])#for point4 this is the coordinate.Interpret as the distance between the center of each buffer and point4
```

But this shows no result for each buffer center distance between it and `point4` is `NaN`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One must remember that the `.distance()` in `geopandas` package in `python` works this way:
`geo-dataframe.distance(Some Shapely Object)` Hence in this case it is unable to find out the distance between a point and other points because there are multiple points of whose distance with other points you want to find out. One solution therefore can be like this:

```
centroid_of_buffers=gdf['Coordinates'].centroid
#dist_a=centroid_of_buffers.distance(a)
#min_dist=centroid_of_buffers.distance(gdf1[gdf1.Coordinates=="POINT (-93.230988 45.234565)"])
gdf_distance_cluster_Nevada=gdf1.distance(gdf['Coordinates'][0].centroid)
gdf_distance_cluster_California=gdf1.distance(gdf['Coordinates'][1].centroid)
gdf_distance_cluster_New_Jersey=gdf1.distance(gdf['Coordinates'][2].centroid)
```

And you can apply sort in the individual `GeoSeries` dataframe to find out the shortest distances between the centroids of each buffer and the points you have plotted.